# Missing header file for reportlab dependency

Tags: python, dependencies

I'm trying to install a dependency on Mac OS X El Capitan:

```
pip install reportlab
```

But I obtain an error:

```
/Users/user/anaconda/include/ft2build.h:56:10: fatal error: 'freetype/config/ftheader.h' file not found

#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>

     ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What is the issue with the missing header file in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the installation was looking for the header in the directory:

```
'user/anaconda/include/freetype/config/ftheader.h'
```

But the file was in the directory

```
'user/anaconda/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftheader.h'
```

So I just copied directory 'freetype' to

```
'user/anaconda/include/'
```

'